# Creating an Access instance from C# code using interop

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop

I am trying to run Access (Office 365) from C# .net code. The reason I am trying to do this is to run an access query that uses VBA. My query is complicated and I'd rather call it as it is rather than convert everything to c#.

I am using VS2015 and .net4 (I have tried other versions of .net to no avail). I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime 2010 (which says it works with VS2015).

When I execute this line I get the error below

```
var accApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
```

Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Here's a dump of my references from my csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="dao, Version=10.0.4504.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Ultimately I would like to get a Recordset back and use it as follows.

```
 var db = accApp.OpenDatabase(@"C:\mypath\mydb.mdb");
 var rs = db.QueryDefs["MyQuery"].OpenRecordset(RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot);
```

I have only gone down this rabbit hole to try and call my query. If there is a better way of doing it I am open to suggestions!

Comment: Do you have Access installed on the machine where this code runs?

Comment: Did you compile your app as anyCPU?

Comment: @Steve yes I have 32-bit Office365 installed, rene I tried 32-bit and 64-bit versions with the and set the target cpu appropriately for each configuration.

Comment: Any reason why you need to use Interop instead of OleDb?

Comment: Yes the reason why is my query calls a vba function which oledb does not support

Comment: Generally speaking, the Win32 error of class not registered means that the appropriate interop runtime is not installed (even down to the the version)....is this a Winforms app or a web app you are trying to do this? Also when you installed it, did you reboot the machine for the registration to take affect?

Comment: It's a winforms app. I rebooted and it made no difference. If I search for that CLSID guid it is in the registry incidentally.

Comment: Office 14.0 is Office 2010 and I don't believe that's offered through Office 365. As I recall, only Office 2013 and 2016 are supplied through Office 365. So you can't use the Access 14 library to run Access installed through an Office 365 account... If you tell me "that's all I found when adding References" then look in the COM and not the .NET tab.